# How can I customize the app icon & label which appear in the action bar in android 3.0 honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

When we develop applications on android 3.0 then by default the application's icon & the label appear on the action bar on Left hand side.

I want to display a different image on the action bar as well as I want a different customized text on it. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//use your custom xml view here

```
View actionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_custom_view, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the action bar logo just add the following code in your manifest file

```
 android:logo="@drawable/youriconimage"
```

Hope it will help you.